# What is channel buffer size?

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to create an asynchronous channel and I've been looking at http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels.

```
c := make(chan int, 10)         // channel with a buffer size of 10
```

What does it mean that the buffer size is 10? What specifically does the buffer size represent/limit?

Comment: See [here](http://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) and further

Comment: See [here](https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering) also helpful. Very straight and easy to understand :)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The buffer size is the number of elements that can be sent to the channel without the send blocking. By default, a channel has a buffer size of 0 (you get this with `make(chan int)`). This means that every single send will block until another goroutine receives from the channel. A channel of buffer size 1 can hold 1 element until sending blocks, so you'd get

```
c := make(chan int, 1)
c <- 1 // doesn't block
c <- 2 // blocks until another goroutine receives from the channel
```

Comment: Good answer.  Effective Go has a nice chapter titled "Concurrency" that expounds on channels. Highly recommended: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: Im messing around with this and make(chan int, 1) allows 3 values to be passed into my channel before blocking(testing it with log.Printlns), and the default is letting 2 in before blocking. Any idea why:

Comment: @Mauricio That sounds pretty weird. I just tested using Go 1.8.3 locally, and also using the "Try Go" functionality at https://golang.org, and in both cases it still behaves as documented in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I was actually misinterpreting the data printing to my console. It does work like you described.

Answer (score 22):

The following code illustrates the blocking of unbuffered channel:

```
// to see the diff, change 0 to 1
c := make(chan struct{}, 0)
go func() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    <-c
}()
start := time.Now()
c <- struct{}{} // block, if channel size is 0
elapsed := time.Since(start)
fmt.Printf("Elapsed: %v\n", elapsed)
```

You may play with the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/KHkrkxCVdQ).

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func receiver(ch <-chan int) {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    msg := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("receive messages  %d from the channel\n", msg)
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    zero_buffer_ch := make(chan int, 0)
    go receiver(zero_buffer_ch)
    zero_buffer_ch <- 444
    elapsed := time.Since(start)    
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed using zero_buffer channel: %v\n", elapsed)

    restart := time.Now()
    non_zero_buffer_ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go receiver(non_zero_buffer_ch)
    non_zero_buffer_ch <- 4444
    reelapsed := time.Since(restart)
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed using non zero_buffer channel: %v\n", reelapsed)
}
```

result:

receive messages  444 from the channel

Elapsed using zero_buffer channel: 505.6729ms

Elapsed using non zero_buffer channel: 0s