# Channel buffer taking one more value than expected in Go

Tags: go, channel

I thought that channels in Go only hold 1 value by default unless the buffer size if specified. I read that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943841/golang-what-is-channel-buffer-size). But when I run this:

```
func main (){
    for i := range numGen(6) {
        log.Println("taking from channel", i)
    }
}

func numGen(num int) chan int {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
            log.Println("passing to channel", i)
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }
    return c
}
```

my output is:

```
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 0
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 1
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 0
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 1
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 2
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 3
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 2
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 3
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 4
2017/06/13 18:09:08 passing to channel 5
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 4
2017/06/13 18:09:08 taking from channel 5
```

which shows that the channel is holding 2 values at a time. Specifying a buffer size like this

```
c := make(chan int, 0)
```

does nothing. Any way I could make it only hold 1, value, not 2?

Comment: `which shows that the channel is holding 2 values at a time.` it doesn't. Your channel does not hold even a single value.

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which shows that the channel is holding 2 values at a time.

Thats not the case. This is how the code executes:

1. The **main** goroutine blocks on a read on the channel
2. The second goroutine writes to the channel *and continues executing*.
3. The second goroutine blocks *at the second write attempt* because noone is reading
4. The **main** goroutine continues executing, prints the read number
5. The **main** goroutine reads another number since someone is writing to it
6. The **main** goroutine prints the read number and blocks on the next read
7. The second goroutine continues executing at step **2.**

There is no buffer, just concurrency.

Comment: I see. The forloop inside the second go routine keeps executing, so the second print statement executes, and stops at the channel-passing. Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    seq := make(chan bool)
    for i := range numGen(6, seq) {
        <-seq
        log.Println("taking from channel", i)
    }
}

func numGen(num int, seq chan bool) chan int {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
            c <- i
            log.Println("passing to channel", i)
            seq <- true // 要保证顺序，这里发送一个信号量。
        }
        close(c)
    }()

    return c
}
```